# Partial serialization of QML object properties

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qml, qt5

I need to serialize **some** properties from a QML object in C++

Example below:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    property color fromcolor: "#0000FF"
    property color tocolor: "#000000"
    property int speed: 5000

    // brave workaround :)
    readonly property string serializable_properties: "fromcolor,tocolor,speed"
    ...
}
```

I only need to serialize the properties given by `serializable_properties`.

Is there a better approach to mark the properties to be serialized without listing their names in a string? This is to prevent bugs when property names are changed.

So far, I used `serializable_properties` as follows:

```
const QMetaObject *metaobject = object->metaObject();
int count = metaobject->propertyCount();
for (int i=0; i<count; ++i)
{
    QMetaProperty metaproperty = metaobject->property(i);
    const char *name = metaproperty.name();
    QVariant value = object->property(name);

    qDebug() << name << value;
}
```

**UPD:**

Thank you for the answer, I improved this approach as follow:

- Enumerate of all properties for class except properties with suffix
  "_p" which marked as private.

  ```
  const QObject *object = qobject_cast<QObject *>( qml_object );
  const QMetaObject *metaobject = object->metaObject();
  int count = metaobject->propertyCount();

  for (int i=metaobject->propertyOffset(); i<count; ++i)
  {
      QMetaProperty metaproperty = metaobject->property(i);
      const char *name = metaproperty.name();
      const QString p_name = QString::fromLatin1(name);
      QVariant value = object->property(name);

      if( p_name.endsWith(QStringLiteral("_p")) ) continue;

      qDebug() << name << value;
  }
  ```

and final QML:

```
Rectangle {
    id: this
    property color fromcolor: "#0000FF"
    property color tocolor: "#000000"
    property int speed: 5000
    property alias mwidth: this.width  // if you want to serialize parent class width
    property int internal_var_p: 5
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way might be to add a prefix or suffix to the property name. Such prefix/suffix then can be easily detected when iterating through the list of properties. Say, your properties could begin with `ser`, or end with `_`:

```
Rectangle {
    // prefix variant
    property color serFromColor: "#0000FF"
    property color serToColor: "#000000"
    // suffix variant
    property color fromcolor_: "#0000FF"
    property color tocolor_: "#000000"
}
```

For the suffix variant, the serialization would then look as follows:

```
QDataStream stream;
const QMetaObject *metaObject = object->metaObject();
int count = metaObject->propertyCount();
// You can start iterating from metaObject->propertyOffset() if you
// are not interested in properties of parent objects.
for (int i=0; i<count; ++i)
{
    QMetaProperty property = metaObject->property(i);
    const char *name = property.name();
    const QString sName = QString::fromLatin1(name);
    if (! sName.endsWith(QStringLiteral("_"))) continue;
    QVariant value = object->property(name);
    stream << sName << value;    
    qDebug() << name << value;
}
```

For the prefix variant you would want to check 3 conditions:

1. Name is longer than 3 characters.
2. Name begins with "ser".
3. If name[3] is a letter, it must be an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

Within qml you need to define a property using a name. If you change this name an older  serialization  won't work any more. That's how it is with serialization. You could achieve downward compatibility using "aliases".

To reduce the error probability in c++ you should use a `const QString` containing the property name instead of using a string (e.g. `"share_property"`) distributed in the code.

For a nice serialization implementation, have a look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Comment: I have rephrased the question may be it will better :)